# Combining Java background Texture and android xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml

i have created  a java game only using java classes. i want to run it on android phones so i used android studio to make to classes and libgdx.

i have Texture as background and use Vector3 and other stuff to make my game complete and be able to make my character go past beyond screen width, having the cam position to follow it.

so i need to add a score system on top right corner. I have only used Textures for my java game so far, both for the background, character and monsters/ obstacles.

how do i add a score label on top right corner so its visible everytime the player is in the "playstate class".

i tried using Jlabel and Jpanel but i never got it visible on my android phone.

what other options are there? is it possible to make a score Texture in photoshop and then have it increased everytime the player makes a score.

in summary:
i want to add a score label on top right corner and have it displayed and visible everytime someone plays the game on the android phone. i have so far only used java classes only. Do i have to use xml layout? if so, then how do i mix it with my java game background?

Comment: i tried to use bitmapfont, but i never got it to display.

Comment: anyone please?.